# How to execute a command that is the arguments to the script?

Tags: bash

I want a bash script, call it `args`, to execute a command that is the arguments to the script.
In particular, I would like this command (note multiple blanks):

```
$./args echo 'foobar    *0x0'
```

to execute this precise command:

```
echo 'foobar    *0x0'
```

I tried this in `args`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
$*
```

but it doesn't work:

```
./args echo 'foobar    *0x0'
+ echo foobar '*0x0'
foobar *0x0
```

Witness the single space, as well as moved single quotes.

With `$@`, the result is exactly the same, so please don't close the question on the account of differences between `$*` and `$@`.  Also, blanks are not my only problem, there is the `*0x0`.

Comment: BTW, using a `.sh` extension for a _bash_ script is less than ideal; it implies that someone can run `sh yourscript`, but doing so won't make bash extensions available. Better to just call it `args` with no extension; see also https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/ (a friend's personal blog, but linked for over a decade from the #bash IRC channel's [factoid on the topic](https://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh) and thus somewhat authoritative).

Comment: Of the linked duplicate questions -- one's answers tell you that `"$@"` **with the quotes** behaves differently than either `$*` or `$@` without the quotes. It is correct in this. The other is even more direct about `"$@"` **with the quotes** being the correct solution to this issue. I stand by the duplicates, or at least, will need further explanation if you want to argue that they don't address the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see, thank you, I saw the various posts about differences between `$*` and `$@` and well, I tried to replace `$*` `$@` (without reading precisely in those posts that also double quotes needed, because, why would I read spend time to read them... title is obvious to try), and did not work.  So there you go.  Actually, I like it that you closed it because... I don't have to answer a question - I am lazy and I answer only 1 question for each 1 asked :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy never mind, closed question is different than deleted question, damn it, I have to go and answer one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
"$@"
```

This expands to all of the command-line arguments with spacing and quoting intact. `$*`, by contrast, is subject to unwanted word splitting and globbing since it's not quoted.